# Looping over lists Python, indexing (basic bootstrap)

Tags: python, list, indexing

Given the following two lists:

```
dates = [1,2,3,4,5]
rates = [0.0154, 0.0169, 0.0179, 0.0187, 0.0194]
```

I would like to generate a list
    df = []

of same lengths as dates and rates (0 to 4 = 5 elements) in 'pure' Python (without Numpy) as an exercise.

df[i] would be equal to:

```
df[0] = (1 / (1 + rates[0])  
df[1] = (1 - df[0] * rates[1]) / (1 + rates[1])
...
df[4] = (1 - (df[0] + df[1]..+df[3])*rates[4]) / (1 + rates[4])
```

I was trying:

```
df = [] 
df.append(1 + rates[0])  #create df[0]  
for date in enumerate(dates, start = 1):
   running_sum_vec = 0
   for i in enumerate(rates, start = 1):
       running_sum_vec += df[i] * rates[i]
df[i] = (1 - running_sum_vec) / (1+ rates[i])
return df
```

but am getting as TypeError: list indices must be integers. Thank you.

Comment: Your index is a tulle since that's what enumerate yields. You need to `for idx, x in enumerate..` even if you are not using the `x` variable

Comment: You are iterating your `running_sum_vec += df[i] * rates[i]` df here where it is not even populated. What should be the result value.

Answer (score 1):

So, the enumerate method return two values: index and value

```
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'a']
>>> for y_count, y in enumerate(x):
...     print('index: {}, value: {}'.format(y_count, y))
... 
index: 0, value: a
index: 1, value: b
index: 2, value: a
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `for i in enumerate(rates, start = 1):`. `enumerate` generates tuples of the index and the object in the list. You should do something like

```
for i, rate in enumerate(rates, start=1):
    running_sum_vec += df[i] * rate
```

You'll need to fix the other loop (`for date in enumerate...`) as well.

You also need to move `df[i] = (1 - running_sum_vec) / (1+ rates[i])` back into the loop (currently it will only set the last value) (and change it to append since currently it will try to set at an index out of bounds).

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate returns both index and entry.
So assuming the lists contain ints, your code can be:

```
df = [] 
df.append(1 + rates[0])  #create df[0]  
for date in dates:
   running_sum_vec = 0
   for i, rate in enumerate(rates[1:], start = 1):
       running_sum_vec += df[i] * rate
df[i] = (1 - running_sum_vec) / (1+ rate)
return df
```

Although I'm almost positive there's a way with list comprehension. I'll have to think about it for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
df = []
sum = 0

for ind, val in enumerate(dates):
    df.append( (1 - (sum * rates[ind])) / (1 + rates[ind]) )
    sum += df[ind]
```